# Removing the selected rows from a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, casting

I am trying to remove the selected rows from a `DataGridView` but I am getting the following error message:

> Specified cast is not valid.

On this line of code:

```
this.DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(ROW => (bool?)ROW.Cells[0].Value == true).ToList().ForEach(x => { this.DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Remove(x); });
```

Second way of trying to remove all the selected rows:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow RowToDelete in DGV_INVOICE.Rows)
{
    object Cell = RowToDelete.Cells["Edit_Checkbox"].Value;

    if (Cell.ToString() == "True")
    {
        // Allow user to delete record from invoice
        DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Remove(RowToDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest looking at the type of `this.DGV_INVOICE.Rows`.  It sounds like it might be complaining that there isn't an explicit conversion

Comment: Try using a ternary to check if `.Value` is null rather than casting to a nullable `bool` and just use a normal `bool`

Comment: @DevNoob there is no property for type for datadridview column as I know and looked for

Comment: If you are binding data to the grid I suggest you remove from the data source, not the grid directly.

Comment: @Crowcoder no I am not binding data form database I am just adding the data from textbox to the datagridview then inserted to database... and I want to remove row from datagridview before inserting data to database

Comment: @samer, ok fair enough. Try looping by index, you cannot alter a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried to loop but looping on them will always delete the half of record not all selected record because after removing the item at index 0, index of items will decrease one and the previous item at index 1 goes to index 0 and so on, then the iterator uses index 1 for next item while the previous item at index 1 is at index 0 now. This way one item will be removed and one item will be bypassed until the end of collection.

Comment: @samir, you can loop backwards, from count to zero.

Comment: @Crowcoder ill update my post and post to you the loop code if you have any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop backwards through your DataGridView's `.Rows` collection so you don't lose the index while removing

```
for (int i = DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    object Cell = DGV_INVOICE.Rows[i].Cells["Edit_Checkbox"].Value;

    if (Cell.ToString() == "True")
        DGV_INVOICE.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
```